# SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) не видит созданные таблицы

Tags: sql-server

Недавно сел изучать БД и столкнулся с проблемой, что в созданные таблицы я не могу ничего добавить и удалить их (потому что SSMS не видит эти объекты)

[image: Сервер не видит данную таблицу,хотя она создана вроде]

Использую я Sql Server 2014 + SSMS версии 17 года (возможно проблема здесь ,но я не понимаю как исправить)

Comment: Просто выполните команду Обновить (правой кнопкой на узле Таблицы).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SSMS не понимает в какой базе ему искать таблицу `Customers`.

**1. Указать явно какую БД использовать с помощью `use`**

Добавить в начало запроса

```
Use test_db;
```

**2. Указать полный путь к БД в запросе**

```
drop table [test_db].[dbo].[Customers]
```

**3. Указать БД test_db по-умолчанию для вашего пользователя**

Безопасность -> Имена входа -> Правой кнопкой по user_name -> Свойства -> База данных по умолчанию -> test_db
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В этом случае ваш вариант будет работать без изменений.

**UPD**

**4. Указать БД в панели "Редактор SQL"**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Предлагаю добавить 4 способ: выбрать необходимую БД в панели "Редактор SQL"

Comment: Спасибо, добавил!